# Did I correctly calculate the specificity and the false negative rate?

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

So I filled out the summary table of the data, but I'm not quite sure if I calculated the specificity and the false negative rate correctly from the table. Can someone please check that I'm doing it right? Thanks

### Data Table:

[image]

### Heres What I got:

Specificity = $\frac{2}{27+2}=6.9$%?

False negative rate = $\frac{2}{267}=0.75$%?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specificity= $\frac{True Negatives}{Healthy}$

FNR= $\frac{False Negatives}{Sick}=1-Sensitivity$

So, if you consider that the test is the SFST Decision and that the Gold Standard is the Real BAC, your answer is correct.